# What if the World adopted the One-Child Policy?

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, earth, population

It may possibly be the toughest decision for world leaders, but what would be the social implications on society if the one-child policy was made universal. How would society react to such a major change. [I understand China had this policy in place but had to abandon it.](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/oct/29/china-abandons-one-child-policy)

Comment: Do you mean all countries? Japan and many European countries will get quite a hit.

Comment: Howdy there Malcom; welcome to Worldbuilding!  I would recommend editing your question to be a bit more specific with regard to what you are looking for in an answer.  As it stands, it's a broad question, and is more of a prompt for discussion; most answers will be what we call "opinion based".  Also, it can currently be interpreted to be a question not about worldbuilding, but about [politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/), which has its own stack exchange site separate from ours.

Comment: You are aware that almost all developed or semi-developed countries have very small or even negative natural population growth? So in effect your question is "what if Nigeria and Bangladesh adopted a one-child policty". (There is a small amount of exaggeration, but it is a *small* amount.) Good luck enforcing such a policy in Nigeria.

Comment: Actually, I disagree with the statement that this question is either *primarily opinion-based* or *too broad*. The OP specifies a scenario and asks about its effects on a specific issue within a world. That's something that we can answer, and answers can be judged on how well they answer the question. Since the scenario described is unlikely to happen in the real world, there's a reasonable worldbuilding component to this. I do however feel that this question suffers from a lack of visible research.

Comment: Do you want it to be followed, circumvented or fought? Or are you asking at what rate different groups might make the choice between them?

Comment: @AlexP: What alternate universe are you deriving your statistics from?  Suggest you check census data for the US, or other developed countries.  AFAIK, only Japan and a few of the former Soviet states have anything close to zero population growth.

Comment: Eventually, the largest group of people will be those who break the rules.

Comment: Education is the only way...

Comment: @jamesqf: The [U.S.A.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demography_of_the_United_States) has a fertility rate of 1.87 children born/woman; Germany, 1.5 children/woman; France, 1.9 children/woman; the [United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demography_of_the_United_Kingdom), 1.8: all are below the replacement rate. Etc. So, what universe do *you* live in? The U.S.A., Germany, France, the U.K. and other such rich countries compensate this dismal natural growth with immigration. Poor Japan cannot, because nobody wants to emigrate to Japan and the Japanese don't accept immigrants anyway.

Comment: This is not a moot point, nor a vague question. There have been many fictional world-building scenarios that are built around strict population control, and very few of them have seriously explored the ramifications. They are indeed very complex. Generational sips will certainly have to face the issue. Apart from politics, what ARE the SOCIAL ramifications? China is now experiencing totally unforeseen societal consequences, apart from just population decline. Imagine a world with entire family lines ending with no male heir. Think beyond population control.

Comment: The conundrum with research on this question is that there is very little unbiased research. You have to delve deeply into the topic. China has had to abandon the one child policy, not because of population control issues, but because of other consequences. Urban females in China are abandoning the traditional family structure, choosing not to have ANY children, and instead pursuing careers. The pressure is now on them to HAVE children. I see a lot of male bias in the answers.

Comment: But if I were to be so brash as to propose an edit to the question to make it truly 'world-building', I would suggest perhaps a re-wording of it along the lines of 'What would be the social implications on a society if a one-child policy were made universal? What social pressures and social norms would change, because of population control?' Take the emphasis off population reduction per say, whether it would or would not mathematically work, and look at the implications of using it as a method to do so. That is a question that far better determines if this method would ultimately work or not.

Comment: @PyRulez, I think this response needs expanding. It is very pertinent. Israel is experiencing the same result. The segment that has the largest population growth, and will soon dominate, is the ultra-orthodox sects that believe in very large families, defying the general trend. How severe are the sanctions against having more than one child? Strong enough to guarantee it? Or would the rule-breakers eventually dominate?

Comment: @AlexP: You are confusing fertility rates with population growth.  Look up census figures for the US (or other countries), e.g. here: https://www.census.gov/popclock/  They show that the population continues to increase, regardless of those fertility rate figures.

Comment: @JustinThyme I was going to make it an answer, but I didn't know how to make it long enough. If want to take the idea and run with it, go ahead.

Comment: @jamesqf: In my initial comment I said **"natural"** population growth. Yes, some people from poor countries, including some poor countries with high natural population growth, emigrate to rich countries. This is normal and to be expected from humans. But in the end it's just a redistribution. The real natural population growth is already limited to a handful of countries. And remember that demography operates with long delays; a fertility rate today below replacement will show up in the population growth 50 years from now.

Comment: @AlexP: How is migration not natural?  I thought non-natural would be e.g. cloned infants from artificial wombs.  But the bottom line remains the same: population continues to increase nearly everywhere.  The 1.87 fertility rate is well above the 1.0 one child rate.

Comment: How the society react is insignificant: in the long run the humans is extinct since you basically halve the population every generation, so, starting with the 7 billion today, in 4 generation you will end about 437 million people (assuming every couple has a child, no woman dies before having a child and of course nobody cheat the system). I don't think it will be sustainable

Answer (score 3):

**Religions that celebrate child-bearing would freak out**

I'm going to start with this because, frankly, it might be the only reason Christians, Jews, Muslims, and Hindus would join hands in a single common cause: and that list constitutes [approximately 90% of the world's population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_religious_populations).  If only one quarter of the group was willing to protest the decision, you're still talking about a group of people 20X larger than [every military on Earth combined](https://www.quora.com/How-many-soldiers-are-there-in-the-world-combined).  And religions are far better organizers than governments.

**Enforcement would be unbelievably intrusive**

The simple reality is that people generally obey the law because the law generally leaves them alone.  But now you're talking about monitoring people in a way that hasn't existed in western cultures since Nazi Germany.  Theoretically, the more civilized/sophisticated/established a country the easier it would be to monitor and control the population.  But it would take an invading army to control southern Africa and it might take nuclear weapons to control India.  Too much land.  Too many people.  Too few "monitors."

But, to be honest, it takes a boatload of effort to get people to comply with laws that are fundamentally against the basics of biology.  Look at what it took to get same-sex marriage equality... and that only affects 1%-3% of the population.  Restricting children tries to control the biology of frankly everybody.  The phrase "police state" just doesn't cut it.

**Cultures that value male children over female children will see an increase in infanticide**

Female infanticide was not the result of China's one-child policy, [the one-child policy was simply the latest excuse to justify it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Female_infanticide_in_China).  However, in those societies that value male children over female the pressure to get that cherished male heir will increase substantially when you get one and only one child to raise.  This has the side-effect of a potential imbalance between genders, meaning there's too many guys and not enough gals a generation or two down the road.  I can't help but unreasonably think that a lot of guys without enough girls will probably result in a global [Lord of the Flies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_of_the_Flies) situation.  It also exacerbates two basic problems with any one-child policy:

**A threatened workforce**

The single biggest problem with one-child population control is that you're creating half the workforce you started with.  This might initially sound like a boon as employers would spend big bucks to secure pretty much anybody.  But the real problem comes when the workforce halves again... then again... and suddenly you have...

**A geriatric society more miserable than you can possibly imagine**

A society with an absolutely enormous number of unemployable senior citizens and a fraction of the number of people needed to provide services.  This problem is horrendous for the first century, but never completely goes away because you are always halving your workforce with each generation (a two-child policy would make a TON more sense....).

> If you don't believe me, read the OP's link about China.

**The most self-centered generation since the Millenials**

I recall watching a documentary 15-20 years ago about the consequences of China's one-child policy and among them was the fact that the children were shamlessly and utterly spoiled.  They were the center of the universe because they were the only one and knew it.  Parents did everything they could to guarantee their one child would be as successful/prepared/provided for as possible and it was creating a generation with more than their fair share of emotional problems.

> Finally, the OP tagged the question [reality-check](/questions/tagged/reality-check), so a final comment is required.  It is entirely unbelievable that a planetary one-child policy would ever come to pass.  Elected officials in democratic countries would soon find themselves flipping burgers.  Monarchs would soon find themselves the focus of attention of a modern Guillotine.  China did it because of invasive governmental control the Nazis would have envied and the world today decries regularly due to human rights violations.  The idea is, IMHO, entirely unbelievable.
>
> Which brings me to my last social consequence of a planetary one-child policy: rebellion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what comparison you are trying to make with your comparison to same sex marriage? Creating those laws is not a restriction for anyone and it takes 0 effort for most people to comply with it.

Comment: @Erik, The effort involved with convincing so many people to look past their own hard-wiring to see the value of granting civil rights to others when it has so little impact on anyone compared to the effort of looking past their own hard-wiring to an actual limitation that affects everybody.  When you look at the history of same-sex marriage, it was like pulling teeth to get those laws passed.  Imagine how people would react when the matter really did affect everyone.

Comment: While I don't agree with the word "hard-wiring" as it seems to be taught behavior, the rest of the explanation makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To keep this from veering into politics, I'm going to totally ignore whether our world is overpopulated or not, and just stick to the biology. Maybe the OP's world isn't overpopulated, or maybe the OP's world has a much more evenly distributed reproduction rate compared to ours; who knows. That's not really relevant to answering the question, though.

For the population in a given area to increase, in the absence of a net immigration (and insofar as we know, there are very few humans on other planets), **on average, each pair of parents must have at least two offspring *which themselves survive long enough to have offspring of their own*.** This is irrespective of the species involved. (Actually, the average must be at least just over two; having exactly two will simply maintain the current population in a species with two sexes.) That's because when the parents die, sufficient offspring must remain such that the net population change is zero or higher. The figure is skewed slightly if the gender ratio is not exactly 1 to 1 male/female, but not sufficiently that it significantly changes the overall picture.

You are proposing a world in which each pair of parents is limited to a single child.

(You'd have to figure out how to handle situations like parents getting twins, but this remains rare enough in humans to not significantly change anything. You'd also have to figure out how to handle people who get children with different significant others; this can probably be worked around pretty simply by just making it one child per woman, rather than one child per couple.)

For simplicity's sake, I'm assuming that everyone in the world just goes along with your scheme. How to make that happen is a different question.

The only logical conclusion, then, is that over time (on the order of generations), by enforcing a one child policy, **as parents die off while having had at most a single child, the total population will decrease.**

Comment: Taken to the furthest extent - Population decreases. Eventually the only choice would be some form of relative. Further along, and the population dies off when there's one person with nobody to have a child with. In short: One child per pair is eventual self-extinction.

Comment: Replacement fertility in humans now is about 2.1. It allows compensating for the higher male to female sex ratio (1.05:1, IIRC) and accidents. Exactly two offsprings for each couple would lead to population decline, albeit slow.

Comment: You might want to add a sentence or two about enlonged life time. If It increases exponentially than it can make up for the exponentially degreasing population.

Answer (score 1):

The question of whether the world is overpopulated or not is open to debate. I believe it is, and that the carrying capacity is roughly 3 billion based on past reading. This allows a reasonably western lifestyle. Lifestyle impacts carrying capacity dramatically. Some believe the capacity is 12 billion. There are points on either side of the debate.

If the world adopted the one child policy, the world would see ideological fighting and some countries not following through.

With a one baby policy, in some countries, some babies would be left to die of exposure. Illegal abortions would increase, and this is a health threat to the mother.

Japan is seeing a decline in birth rate and also in sex, and this is thought due to economics and social media.

In your world that you are building, I suggest incorporating these elements if you are going for dystopia. If you are going for a happy solution to overpopulation, try education and free birth control first. Also try to eliminate sexism. If the role of women is to have babies, then telling them they should only have one is a problem. But, if a woman's role is not to have babies, then one child is more easily acceptable by all.

Comment: European countries also face low fertility rates. This trend started earlier than in Japan. Interestingly, there is some research suggesting that full gender equity would result in higher fertility rates, hopefully, all the way to replacement rates. Perhaps, an ideal situation for voluntary sub-replacement rates includes 100% employment, good medicine, easy contraception, high educational attainment for women, post-industrial economy, and mild gender inequality. In this case, the cost of having an offspring goes up and parents opt out for just one child.

Comment: The reality in China has resulted in exactly the OPPOSITE of full gender equity. Females have gained the social power in relationships. It is now lopsided in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Justin Thyme I wonder what  metric you are using. The gender pay gap is large and there are other inequities that favor men in china. See this: http://www.catalyst.org/knowledge/women-workforce-china

Comment: Oh Sorry @Justin Thyme , you stated your metric, up vote. By many metrics, men are ahead.

Comment: The gender pay gap in middle-class China is greatly exaggerated by Western propaganda. A google search produces hits by organizations that WANT there to be a pay gap, and use selective statistics to demonstrate it. Yes the rural areas are entrenched in gender inequality, but apart from the desire for male heirs, the females tend to wield the power. Remember, China does NOT equate money with power or social status. A more unbiased [link](http://epaper.chinadailyasia.com/asia-weekly/article-11614.html)

Comment: ctd Also see '61 percent of all respondents in China – both men and women – think there is equal pay among both genders. This figure has increased in China while it has decreased in other countries. China is the only country where more female respondents compared to male respondents believe there is equal pay between genders.' from 'China Makes Advances in Gender Diversity despite Drop in Women Participation Rate' [link](http://www.hrinasia.com/recruitment/china-makes-advances-in-gender-diversity-despite-drop-in-women-participation-rate/)

Comment: But I wholeheartedly agree that this question seems to hinge on the predominant cultural status bias that the roll of the female is to have children. It begs the question be asked, 'Does a one-child policy put pressure on this traditional societal norm?' And the answer from China is that 'yes, it certainly does. Limiting females to one child totally demolishes their traditional roll image as the bearer of children.' It seems to be fast-tracking gender equality with respect to career ambitions. Collateral damage of the policy with far greater social and population growth implications.

Answer (score 1):

China is now experiencing the caveat of the juxtaposition of a one-child policy with a cultural preference for a male heir. There are now some 40 million more males than females in China (imagine the population of Canada being only male, and you have a scope of the numbers). Since it is the female (not specifically the couple) that can have only one child, you can see the problem. Millions of males without heirs, male or female. Entire family lines die off with no descendants.

I don't think ANYONE in China foresaw this coming, although in hindsight it was inevitable.

The bottom line is that this proposed one-child policy world wide would interlink with other social norms and conventions and would have completely unforeseeable consequences.

In the extreme, I could foresee dominant males taking on several wives to themselves, in order to ensure a male heir from at least one. Then, of course, childless, heirless  males would certainly rebel against the system.

Comment: On the bright side, it appears that many if not most of those missing women are not really missing after all, but rather just [hidden from the watchful eye of the state bureaucracy](https://news.ku.edu/2016/11/22/study-finds-chinas-missing-girls-theory-likely-far-overblown). Human ingenuity in action against an inhuman policy.

Comment: @AlexP, If you mean the absent Chinese female, they are not at all missing. They are dead. As in aborted. As in never born. As in sex-based infanticide. That is not speculation, that is established evidentiarily.

Answer (score 0):

In a totalitarian state such as China this was feasible. In Western democracies it would not be possible due to legal considerations such as Human rights and constitutional prohibitions. Also simple disobedience on the part of the population would render it unworkable.

But assuming this was possible (a very big if) say if revolutions replaced democracies with dictatorships, then yes it would eventually be effective. In the short term the population might still continue to increase for a while if a there was a large proportion of young people, but in the long run it would be effective. In fact in extremis it would wipe out the human race (assuming real world practical considerations are not taken into consideration as I had to do when I assumed this was possible in the first place).
Any number of half-way house situations could be imagined where the one child policy was only partially effective. These would be dependent on circumstances and the outcome would be a matter of opinion.

Comment: In Western democracies it would not be unnecessary since their population already decreases.

Comment: Modern China is definitely NOT a totalitarian state. It is a socially engineered state. There is a very big difference. In China the people collectively decide what kind of homogeneous state they want, and the leaders design and structure the system to provide it. It is absolutely impossible for one billion people to be dominated by only a few. if only one percent revolt, that is over 10 million people. The entire Chinese army has only two and a half million soldiers. It is the people collectively that oppose social unrest, and demand conformity..

Answer (score 0):

Well Ender´s game has a similar idea to it except it was a two child policy and having more than two just means extra taxes and no educational help such as scholarships. You might want to look at that for inspiration. But overall if having more than one child policy was actually enforced then sure it would help combat overpopulation. If the punishment for breaking this was a large fine then i´m sure that it would stop many people from having more kids then they are supposed to. But if you had it enforced by jail time over a year as well as a fine then i´m sure it would work. If the governments are totally all in with this policy and god forbid have death penalty as the punishment then there´s almost no way it could fail.

Comment: Yes, there IS a way. Dominant males would build harems to guarantee a male heir. Many to one families. What do the men who are left out do? Family oligarchs would be created. Population would decline a LOT faster than one might think.Too fast. There would probably be a rebound.